# Angular: Change button text in shared component dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a shared component in login page and sign up page.

Unfortunately, I'm able to change a text in button dynamically.

**Shared component**

`<button ion-button block (click)="someMethod()">{{ submitLabel }}</button>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'registration-form',
  templateUrl: 'registration-form.html'
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent {

  public submitLabel: string = '';

  constructor() {}

  public changeLabel(text: string) {
    this.submitLabel = text;
  }
}
```

---

**login.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <registration-form></registration-form>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**login.ts**

```
import { RegistrationFormComponent } from "@my-app/components/registration-form/registration-form";

export class LoginPage {

  @ViewChild('RegistrationFormComponent') registrationSubmitBtn: RegistrationFormComponent;

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    // TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeLabel' of undefined
    this.registrationSubmitBtn.changeLabel('Log In'); 
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried passing the component itself to @ViewChild instead of the string? `@ViewChild(RegistrationFormComponent) registrationSubmitBtn: RegistrationFormComponent;`

Comment: @nicowernli It works!!!!!!! Thank you nicowernli :)